# How do I add values to the bars in a Stacked Bar chart in Pygal?

Tags: python, charts, pygal

I have a StackedBar chart created using pygal see below:
[image]

And I would like to add labels to each of the stacked bars a bit like those from the documentation for Bar charts (see below .. from the pygal documentation).  The method of adding these labels described in the documentation for Bar charts does not seem to work for StackedBar charts.

[image]

What I'm trying to get is the numeric values printed on the graph bars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the `print_values` argument when creating your `StackedBar` object.  For example, the following code creates the chart shown below:

```
import pygal
chart = pygal.StackedBar(print_values=True)
chart.add("Series A", [None, None, 40, 20, 10])
chart.add("Series B", [80, 60, 40, 40, 30])
chart.add("Series C", [20, 40, 20, 40, 60])
chart.render()
```

[image: Stacked bar chart with labels]

The different parameters that can be used when creating chart objects are listed in the [*chart configuration* section of the docs](http://pygal.org/en/stable/documentation/configuration/chart.html).

Comment: This works as advertised, thanks.  Also the values can be formatted using chart.value_formatter setting (e.g. number of digits) and the font, font size, color etc can be set using the style option.  Pygal seems quite good/versatile.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add for each stack

```
   bar_chart = pygal.StackedBar()
   bar_chart.add('Undercharged', [0,1,2...])
   bar_chart.add('Ok', [0,1,2...])
   bar_chart.add('Grounding', [0,1,2...])
   bar_chart.add('Overcharge', [0,1,2...])
   bar_chart.render()
```

Comment: That's what I'm doing.  The problem is that I want the probabilities on the graph.  I've clarified my question.